# AWS SQS policy condition based on requestTag or similar

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js

Hi guys currently I'm trying to allow any Lmabda within my account with specific Tag to send messages into a QUEUE i don't want to modify every Lamba role for this.

I've tried with aws:RequestTag/tag-key and aws:PrincipalTag which only works with the Role tags.

[In this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) the mention `When a principal makes a request to AWS, AWS gathers the request information into a request context.`
I would like to know if there is a way to intercept or decode the whole HTTP request context created by the AWS SDK and actually what metadata is being sent to the SQS service.

Thank you guys

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to permit access to a resource based on the tags on a different resource (unless that resource is a principal).  The request context described in the documentation that you quoted is gathered on the server side and used to evaluate request authorization; it is not accessible to the SDK.

Comment: That totally makes sense.